# has_many :through with class_name and foreign_key not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, has-many-through

i need to create parental relation i.e child and parent relation within a customer model. For storing information about parent and child, i have created a join table i.e ParentalRelation.
My customer model is:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parental_relations
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Customer', foreign_key: 'child_id', through: :parental_relations
  has_one :parent, foreign_key: 'parent_id', class_name: 'Customer', through: :parental_relations, source: :parent
end
```

My parental_relation model is:

```
class ParentalRelation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Customer'
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'Customer'
end
```

I am trying to get data by:

```
Customer.first.children
```

But i am not getting data. getting like this even when there is data:

> Customer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x3fe49a819750

It would be really great help if anybody could help me out. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if parent_relation has column `parent_id` and `child_id`
I believe it should be

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children_relations, class_name: 'ParentalRelation', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Customer', foreign_key: 'parent_id', through: :children_relations, source: :child
  
  has_one :parent_relation, class_name: 'ParentalRelation', foreign_key: 'child_id'
  has_one :parent, foreign_key: 'parent_id', class_name: 'Customer', through: :parent_relation, source: :parent
end
```

according to your relation, Rails will excute sql `SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" INNER JOIN "parental_relations" ON "customers"."id" = "parental_relations"."child_id" WHERE "parental_relations"."customer_id" = $1 LIMIT $2`

But I don't know your table struct. So you can read the sql in rails console and find out how Rails find records. It should help you to solve this problem.

Comment: parent relation is defined by:
has_one :parent, foreign_key: 'child_id', class_name: 'Customer', through: :parent_relation, source: :parent

Answer (score 0):

Given you have `customer has_one :parent` in your model, it looks like you are trying to create a one-to-many relationship.  If this is correct, you don't need a join table.  You only need a join table if you are creating a many-to-many relationship.

To do this as a one-to-many, remove the ParentalRelation model and table and update your customer class to something like this:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to parent, class_name: "Customer"
  has_many children, class_name: "Customer", foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

Check out the guides here for creating a self joining table:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

Once you have that, you should be able to do this:

```
Customer.first.children
```